# How to set up conditional routes with Django?

Tags: django, routes, django-views

I'm trying to switch from Pyramid to Django for a small project. The website can be accessed through multiple subdomains, and I want the same app to be able to route a request to a view only if certain conditions are met.

For example, route http://mysite.com/signup to the standard signup controller, and http://api.mysite.com/signup to the API controller.

Is there any Django equivalent for Pyramid [route predicates](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/urldispatch.html#custom-route-predicates)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [django-hosts](http://django-hosts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

```
pip install django-hosts
```

Comment: Thanks. You literally saved my day =)

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had a post on it a while ago. I hope this helps: http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/

Comment: Thanks. The last comment gave me a solution. But it still seems a little "hackish" to me. Much less elegant than the Pyramid solution :/